Python: wait for all threads to reach one point in the code before continuing
def setsystemdate(epoch)
    # set system date to epoch

# this function uses a huge amount of file pointers that I want to keep open for efficiency
def longrunningfunc(elem1, start_time, end_time):
    for newdate in range(start_time, end_time, 100000):
        setsystemdate(newdate)
        # need to change the date of the machine to create file with correct metadata
        # copy a huge amount of file to a new folder
        # create huge amount of link

elems = ["elem1","elem2","elem3"....."elem150"]

# that is working perfectly
for elem in elems:
    longrunningfunc(elem, start_epoch, end_epoch)
   
# Now i'd like to be able to run code like this. 
# My issue is how to synchronize my threads so they wait for each other to set the system date. 
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
    executor.map(lambda kargs: longrunningfunc(**kargs), elems)

This code takes a list of folders and for each elem it creates a backlog of files which are a copy of the current element, but to have it consistent I need to change the system date so that the birth date is properly set.
How can I make all my threads wait for each other before starting the new epoch so they can write files in a bit more parallel manner?
I don't really want to switch over to doing all folder for one epoch, because doing one elem at a time allows me to maintain 50k filedescriptor per elem open to copy them many times faster.
I was thinking of creating a separate thread to manage date change, but then I have no idea how all the threads could synchronize each other and wait for the date to be set.

The normal way to wait for all threads to reach a known point and wait is a barrier, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Barrier

looks interesting I will look at that thank you very much.

The barrier sounds like a good solution, but if you have 10 threads and 20 tasks, does calling barrier.wait release the thread? Also how do you know which thread will get woken up first to call barrier.reset() for the next iteration.

@matt that is up to me to figure things out I guess. but it's the best idea I saw so far because it does exactly what I want.

You might consider a generator object. You yield at the end of each loop. That will "keep your file pointers open" and your map just calls next.

What metadata exactly would be incorrect if you did not set the system time the way you do? Could it not be corrected after the fact from data you could save at the moment the metadata is incorrectly set?

@Marichyasana Not my choice. a dev rely on the attribute : birth date which has no interface in userland to set :-/

Here is a basic example using a Barrier
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import threading, concurrent.futures

barrier = threading.Barrier(20)


def longRunningFunction( a, b):
    for i in range(10):
        print("task: ", a, "loop", i)
        task = b.wait();
        if task == 0:
            b.reset()
    return a
tasks = [ { "a" : i, "b" : barrier } for i in range(20) ]
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers= len(tasks)) as executor:
    futures = executor.map(lambda kargs: longRunningFunction(**kargs), tasks)
for f in futures:
    print(f, "completed")

The max workers needs to be at least as many as there are tasks because the tasks will not release a thread when waiting.
Another way to do it would be to use a generator, that would be a bit more async of an async style. Where the action releases control until it is started again.
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import threading, concurrent.futures

def longRunningFunction( a):
    for i in range(10):
        print("task: ", a, "loop", i)
        yield "%d-%d"%(a,i)
tasks = [ longRunningFunction(i) for i in range(20) ]
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers= 10) as executor:
    for i in range(10):
        futures = executor.map(lambda args: args.__next__(), tasks)
        for f in futures:
            print(f)

            

All of the tasks need to finish and then the next round begins. The generator methods do not end until the method finishes without a yield so the files stay open.
